# Проверка мобильных браузеров на сервере и на клиенте

Tags: mobile, javascript, php

Доброго времени суток - вопрос заключается в следующем: есть ли готовое решение позволяющие осуществлять проверки вида:

```
 if(mobileBrowser) {}
 else {/* desktop browser */}
```

Интересует как сервер так и клиент.

На php пока нашел только [это](http://www.manhunter.ru/webmaster/272_opredelenie_mobilnih_brauzerov_na_php.html)

И вообще - кто что использует для этих целей?

---

особо актуально решение на JS.

**upd** еще вариант - [Яндекс Директор](http://api.yandex.ru/detector/doc/dg/concepts/detector-request.xml), но мне бы очень не хотелось бы делать лишних запросов...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовал решение предоставленное [от сюда](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/), практически все необходимые реализации. Пользовался под питоном, не много поправил регулярки, но работает вроде корректно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* ------------------------ *
 * CSS Browser Selector 4.0 *
 * ------------------------ */

function css(u){
    var ua=u.toLowerCase(),
    is=function(t){
        return ua.indexOf(t)>-1
    },
    g='gecko',
    w='webkit',
    s='safari',
    o='opera',
    m='mobile',
    h=document.documentElement,
    b=[(!(/opera|webtv/i.test(ua))&&/msie\s(\d)/.test(ua))?
        ('ie ie'+RegExp.$1):is('firefox/2')?
        g+' ff2':is('firefox/3.5')?
        g+' ff3 ff3_5':is('firefox/3.6')?
        g+' ff3 ff3_6':is('firefox/3')?
        g+' ff3':is('gecko/')?
        g:is('opera')?
        o+(/version\/(\d+)/.test(ua)?
        ' '+o+RegExp.$1:(/opera(\s|\/)(\d+)/.test(ua)?
        ' '+o+RegExp.$2:'')):is('konqueror')?
        'konqueror':is('blackberry')?
        m+' blackberry':is('android')?
        m+' android':is('chrome')?
        w+' chrome':is('iron')?
        w+' iron':is('applewebkit/')?
        w+' '+s+(/version\/(\d+)/.test(ua)?
        ' '+s+RegExp.$1:''):is('mozilla/')?
        g:'',is('j2me')?
        m+' j2me':is('iphone')?
        m+' iphone':is('ipod')?
        m+' ipod':is('ipad')?
        m+' ipad':is('mac')?
        'mac':is('darwin')?
        'mac':is('webtv')?
        'webtv':is('win')?
        'win'+(is('windows nt 6.0')?' vista':''):is('freebsd')?
        'freebsd':(is('x11')||is('linux'))?
        'linux':'','js'];

    c = b.join(' ');
    h.className += ' '+c;
    return c;
};
css(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: И вам спасибо =)