# Как определить что пользователь зашел на сайт с телефона?

Tags: java

Как определить что пользователь зашел на сайт с телефона?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[API Яндекс.Детектор](http://api.yandex.ru/detector/) - все написано и расписано, главное, научиться пользоваться :)

Answer (score 0):

Используя 'Meta' данные запросов, вопрос очень похож на этот: [проверка мобильных браузеров на сервере и на клиенте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/70122/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5).